# How to select just the available rooms on a reservation system?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a reservation system for a hotel and I don't know how to select just the available rooms?
I have two tables:
table of rooms with called "chambre" it have: `id, libelle` and table called" reservation_client" it has: `id, id_client, id_chambre, start, end`.
For the start and end they are the start date of reservation and the end of reservation

This is my select form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chambre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="id_chambre">
            <option>Selectionnez une chambre</option>

            <?php 
                 /*echo $req2=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM reservation_client WHERE $donnees["start"]!==$_POST["start"] ' )/*or die (print_r($bdd->errorinfo()))*/
                $req=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM chambre' )/*or die (print_r($bdd->errorinfo()))*/;

                $req2=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM reservation_client ' );
                    while ($donnees = $req->fetch() ) { 

                  echo"<option  value='".$donnees['id']."'>".($donnees['libelle']) ."</option> "  ;                                                 
                      }                   
              ?>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this code but without any result:

```
$req2=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM reservation_client WHERE start<end AND end>star ' );
```

Comment: Is the table called reservation or reservation_client

Comment: sorry its reservation_client

Comment: Why are you using 'start<end AND end>star'?

Comment: because i don't want to select a room that's is between the start and the end

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join the table, if you don't know how to do that then do some research into mysql LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN.  In this case you want to LEFT JOIN  so that you can include rows without a matching reservation.  I can't write it exactly becaus I don't know your tables but this example should give you an idea:

```
SELECT * FROM chambres c
LEFT JOIN reservation_client rc ON rc.chambre = c.id
WHERE rc.date BETWEEN (your date range)
AND rc.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thank you, just a question do i need to add a date column in my reservation_client table because i have just two date : start an end

Comment: If you're using two dates you can use your original idea of start_date <=:date and end_date.... Etc

Comment: but my original idea does not give me any result !

Comment: I can't write the exact query you need, take a look at the code in the answer and think about which of your columns you need to use in the WHERE clause.  If you are using start and end dates then substitute the condition.  You got no results previously because you did no join, experiment with some different things - that's what learning is all about. I'm sure you will be able to use the join with your own WHERE conditions to get the result you want with a little experimentation