# Checking room availability for hotel booking system

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check available rooms in booking system so I have two tables: table of rooms called chambre (`id`, `name`) and table reservation_client (`id`, `start`, `end`, `id_chambre`) the start and end are the check in and checkout dates.

My query is:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM chambre 
 WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id_chambre 
       FROM reservation_client 
     WHERE end < '2019-07-20'  
        AND start > '2019-07-19 '
    )";
```

But its not giving me any result.

Comment: i change them but still not working

Comment: What is the database schema for the date fields? Are they actually strings, dates or datetimes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select just the available rooms on a reservation system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819952/how-to-select-just-the-available-rooms-on-a-reservation-system)

Comment: @msg they are DATE

Comment: Please provide sample data (in like http://sqlfiddle.com/ ) so we can troubleshoot this query. We dont even know if in your sample data there are any chambre entries that could be selected by this query

Answer (score -1):

**There is extra space in the value for the column *start*. Please remove that and check. Should work.**  You can use below query

$sql = "SELECT * FROM chambre WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_chambre FROM reservation_client WHERE end < '2019-07-20' AND start > '2019-07-19')";

Also, as suggested in comments you should post sample data or table schema for our better understanding.